# How to verify signout and redirect to sign in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, logout

In order to signout from my webapp, I need to call a json to signout (clear all cookies)

```
logout:->
    $.get('/signout.json')
```

However, I am unsure how I can refresh the page + redirect the web page to the address i want e.g. /#!/signin? after the signout is successful.

Comment: What web framework are you using? e.g. ASP.NET, php etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to solve it in javascript just use `window.location = "yourlinkhere"`

I use the same sort of thing to determine if I have to show a push notification.
I also use asp.net and vb.net so not sure if it will help you but you will get a basic idea of what to do :)

```
//admin is the controller the second is the function.
 $.post("/admin/UpdateBrainBattle/
```

That function will return a json. in this case its about submitting a form. so you check if the form is valid or not.
in the end it shows this:

```
 Return Json(New With {.status = "error"})
```

or when its good its with `.status = "ok"`
Then I get the json back on my page.
This is the whole function(including the post function)

```
$.post("/admin/UpdateBrainBattle/" + sessionId, { questionId: key, startTimeField: startTimeField, startDateField: startDateField },
                   function(data) {
                        if (data.status == 'ok'){
                         parentLi.find('li.onedit').hide();
                         parentLi.find('li.onview').show();
                         parentLi.find('div.dateTimeBlock div.view').html(data.value).show();
                         parentLi.find('div.dateTimeBlock div.edit').hide();
                         $('.errorBlockSummary').hide();
                         }
                         else
                         {
                            parentLi.find('span.errorBlock').show();
                            $('.errorBlockSummary').show();
                         }
                   });
```

This way you can tell your page, if everything was succesful go to this page, otherwise take this action.
Hope this helped you a bit on your way :)

Edit: noted you used a $.get instead, it can work exactly the same way as long as the function you call to has a return value you should be fine.